# Define Classes and many to many Relations for Parse.com .net

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

I am trying to get some data into Parse.com, and I am accustomed to working with MVC and NHibernate and SQL Server, where I define my entities as separate classes, and then have mapping files.  I know I want to have some many to many relationships, and I am not sure as to how to define them in my parse.com project to get the right relationships created.

Here is what I would like to have as classes, but I am not sure how to establish the relationships.

```
[ParseClassName("Ingredient")]
public class Ingredient :ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("weight")]
    public decimal Weight
    {
        get { return GetProperty<decimal>(); }
        set { SetProperty<decimal>(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("percentage")]
    public decimal Percentage
    {
        get { return GetProperty<decimal>(); }
        set { SetProperty<decimal>(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("unit")]
    public string Unit
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }
}

[ParseClassName("Recipe")]
public class Recipe : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }

    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

} 

[ParseClassName("Category")]
public class Category : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
    }

    public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
```

I would like for an ingredient to be in more than one recipe, though with different quantities.  I know how I would map this in NHibernate, but I don't understand how to create the relationship correctly in Parse.

I am not getting it from the regular parse documentation.